# Possible to hide specific nodes in plotly Sankey diagram?

Tags: python, graph, plotly, data-visualization, sankey-diagram

My objective is to produce a Sankey diagram in plotly (in Python) that does *not* have all terminal nodes justified on the right. My data is such that certain flows have only one or two intermediate nodes and others have many intermediate nodes. I would like for short flows to be highlighted by visibly terminating before reaching the right edge of the graph. As far as I can tell, there is not currently a way to do this.

However, I thought that a workaround might be to just include dummy nodes and links in my data as needed and either set their visibility to `False` or make them completely transparent. But so far I have only found visibility and transparency/opacity approaches that apply to the entire graph.

So, is there any way to do any of the following:

1. left-justify a Sankey diagram (best option)
2. change visibility of individual nodes/links (good enough)
3. change transparency of individual nodes/links (also good enough)

Answer (score 0):

For any nodes that you want to be "left-aligned" (i.e. end before reaching the farthest left of the page)....

Give these nodes a path to the most "right-aligned" terminal node, but set the color of the path to fully transparent #00000000. This should do the trick.

Comment: hello, I am facing the same problem. Have you get a solution for this? If yes, could you help share?